# How to embed replit in iframe dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to embed replit here https://jsfiddle.net/69ajeskL/2/
It doesn't work why ?

html:

```
<div id="placeHolder">
</div>
```

js:

```
let placeHolder = document.getElementById('placeHolder');
let iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
placeHolder.appendChild(iframe);

iframe.src = "https://replit.com/@SilkyS/HelloWorld?v=1";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you guys not know about
?embed=true

you can even do
?lite=1&outputonly=1

eg:
https://replit.com/@SilkyS/HelloWorld?embed=true
Or:
https://replit.com/@SilkyS/HelloWorld?lite=1&outputonly=1

I would recommend
?lite=1&outputonly=1
because it is more user friendly. (No, it does NOT work on the homepage of replit.com)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

You can't embed `https://replit.com/@SilkyS/HelloWorld?v=1` in an `<iframe>` because it has its [`X-Frame-Options` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) set to `DENY`.

You can, however, embed the page embedded by that page, `https://ca96c5e0-a1a8-4010-a7eb-cc3d7c86ad3b.id.repl.co/`.

Answer (score 1):

It related to the origins and your iframe tag url must be in the same origin.
Check this answer to similar question: [Firefox blocks the loading of HTML iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66624785/16706782)